# What is the Q-factor when doing Pi-matching?

Tags: impedance-matching

What is the Q-factor when doing Pi-matching?

There appears to be multiple Q factor formulas and I am not sure which to use.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the bandwidth you need, on the tolerance for initial uncertainty of the PCB parasitics and L % and C %.

Lossy PCBs may prevent achieving the Q you designed for.

Plan to use lots of Vias around the PI, to strap GND metals together.